# iOS Simulator Displaying App Incorreclty

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have no idea why, but all of a sudden my iOS simulator is displaying my app funny.  It is cut off and seems to be zoomed in. Below is a screen of my story board and my simulator.

[image]

Comment: what does it look like on device? You probably haven't added the correct constraints. Show the constraints you've added.

Comment: Did you set up [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)? Using Auto Layout, your application will scale automatically on a per-device basis.

Comment: Does the app look like this in other iPhone's simulator too?

Comment: Yea, and it happened out of no where.  I have run these apps before, and they were fine.

Comment: You can use the view debugger to look at how the constraints are being set at runtime. You can also setup a preview pane on the right-hand side of the screen so you can review your changes at design-time. But I don't see any constraints on your storyboard so that is probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the output window if there are any constraints being broken.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all constraint which are added in size inspector. As default it stick to left and up with size fit. So remove it.